# Error: Type 'ExcelPackage' is not defined while using EPPLUS dll to export to excel

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, excel, epplus

I am new to Windows Forms, 
I have a requirement to export a DataTable to excel. I found out that I need to have to Microsoft Office installed on my machine to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` but I do not have that installed.

I came across EPPLUS. I downloaded and added the reference to the dll in my project. But  problem is that it still shows me error.

I used `Imports OfficeOpenXml` but this one gives me an error. When I add reference once again, the error disappears and the `ExcelPackage` (where I was getting error gets color , same as a any keyword.) But when I build the application or run the application it again gives me the same error.

```
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
  ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Accounts");
  ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);
  pck.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the Target .NET Framework:

1. On the **Project** menu, click *ProjectName* **Properties**.
2. In the left column of the property pages window, select the **Application** tab
3. In the **Target Framework** drop-down list, select the "**.NET Framework 4**". In the verification dialog box that appears, choose the **Yes** button.